# Doxygen project brief not including spaces

Tags: configuration, project, doxygen, documentation-generation, configuration-files

I am developing a project and using Doxygen for the documentation. In the config file, I have put `PROJECT_BRIEF = dynamic and effective`, but for some weird reason on the HTML, it is appearing as `dynamicandeffictive` without spaces in between. Is there some sort of configuration which stops this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are  spaces in the `PROJECT_BRIEF`, the sentence should be in quotes like:

```
PROJECT_BRIEF = "dynamic and effective"
```

(Pity that you didn't tell us which version of doxygen you are using, so I tried it with the current version 1.8.18, but most likely it will have the same effect on older versions).

Comment: Thanks, @albert this works now, I know it might be a bit late but I have version 8.1.13

Comment: Well actually you are your time well ahead, the current version is 1.8.18 and you are already on 8.1.13 ;-)

Comment: oh sorry I meant 1.8.13